# Selecting data from multiple tables with different columns name and remove the duplications in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that I want to join

`order` table

```
|   date    | deliver_date |
----------------------------
| 2011-09-01 | 2011-09-13  |
| 2011-09-05 | 2011-09-15  |
```

`deliver` table

```
| deliver_date |
----------------
| 2011-09-01   |
| 2011-09-13   |
```

`return` table

```
|return_date|
--------------
| 2011-09-04 |
| 2011-09-05 |
```

The data inside 3 tables contains same date.

I want to join the date from 3 tables and display without duplications

The expected result that I want to get something like this

```
 2011-09-01,2011-09-04,2011-09-05,2011-09-13
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by "joining", it doesn't seem like you mean a join in the traditional sense. Could you give an example?

Comment: i already edit the question and give the example thx for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `union` not `join` :

```
select date from order

union 

select deliver_date from order

union

select deliver_date from deliver

union

select return_date from return
```

Comment: sorry to bother you grisha, how about there is a deliver_date column inside order table i use SELECT * from order and the rest is same but it don't give any result, advise?

Comment: Do you want both `date` and `deliver_date` from `order` table in your result or just one of them ?

Comment: i want it both date and deliver date from order table in my result, so all the data will be displayed